# Create historicity dynamically

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have such a problem: I need to calculate the state of customer dynamically changing a date range.

I have 2 types of customers: Active, Inactive and Lost. 
Active - 3 years, Inactive = Active + 1 year, Lost = Inactive + 1 year. For example, a customer bought a product on 03-03-2018. He is Active: 03-03-2018: 03-03-2021, Inactive: 04-03-2021: 03-03-2022, Lost - 04-03-2022
When I enter Period Start and Period End Date, I need to get the current state of the customer. I want to create historicity dynamically.

```
DECLARE @StartPeriod DATE = '2019-01-01';
DECLARE @EndPeriod DATE = '2019-11-23'; 

SELECT  @EndPeriod AS EndPeriod
    ,StartDate
    ,EndDate
    ,CustomerId
    ,ProductId
    ,CustomerType = CASE
    WHEN EndDate >=  @EndPeriod THEN 'Active'
    WHEN EndDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -12, @EndPeriod)  AND EndDate < @EndPeriod
    THEN 'Inactive'
    WHEN EndDate <  EndPeriod THEN 'Lost'
    ELSE 'unknown' END
FROM Table
WHERE EndDate  between  @StartPeriod and @EndPeriod
```

The condition `WHERE EndDate between @StartPeriod and @EndPeriod` is bad since I get not all data. Example, customer is Active- 2016-11-24: 2019:11-24. Using my range above I don't get this customer, but he is Active in that Period.
How I can realize it?

When I choose such range:

```
DECLARE @StartPeriod DATE = '2019-01-01';
DECLARE @EndPeriod DATE = '2019-11-24';
```

I get such result (and it's correct):

[image]

When I choose such range:

```
DECLARE @StartPeriod DATE = '2019-01-01';
DECLARE @EndPeriod DATE = '2019-11-23';
```

I get an empty result. But the customer is active (It is because `Where` condition is wrong).

Different customers have different `End Date`. But I need to know the state of each in the selected period. I don't know how I can implement such case.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results, as tabular text.

Comment: Does everyone have an end date? You might need to specify end date between that range OR no end date exists.

Comment: you need to provide a sample of your data

Comment: I provided an example in the topic above

Answer (score 0):

You can't use between for this example because as you have seen, `EndDate` could be outside the period you are interested in. Instead you need to check that `EndDate` is `>=` the start of the period you are interested in `AND` that `StartDate` is `<=` the end of the period you are interested in. You might need to play with whether it should be `>=` & `<=`, or `>` & `<` or come combination depending on how you want to treat the edge cases.

I've also handled the case where `EndDate` is null.

```
declare @Table table (id int, StartDate date, EndDate date, CustomerId int, ProductId int)

insert into @Table (id, CustomerId, ProductId, StartDate, EndDate)
values (1, 1, 1, '2016-11-24', '2019-11-24')

declare @StartPeriod date = '2019-01-01', @EndPeriod date = '2019-11-23'; 

select @EndPeriod as EndPeriod
    , StartDate
    , EndDate
    , CustomerId
    , ProductId
    , CustomerType = case
    when EndDate >=  @EndPeriod then 'Active'
    when EndDate >= dateadd(month, -12, @EndPeriod)  AND EndDate < @EndPeriod then 'Inactive'
    when EndDate < @EndPeriod then 'Lost'
    else 'unknown' end
from @Table
-- where EndDate between @StartPeriod and @EndPeriod
where StartDate <= @EndPeriod and (EndDate isnull or EndDate >= @StartPeriod)
```

Note how I setup the data for testing using a table variable. If you do something similar for future questions you will get your answers fast, because you've made it as easy as possible for someone to answer.